# how to cast input in "SELECT * FROM PRODUCT LIMIT CAST(select CAST('1' AS UNSIGNED)), 5"?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select * from product limit (select CAST('1' AS UNSIGNED)) ,5;
```

this will give error for syntax

also tried create view to replace the (select CAST('1' AS UNSIGNED)), which still doesnt work

I am using mysql.

Comment: LIMIT parameter cannot be an expression.

Comment: is there anyway to achieve this tho? the aws server automatically converts incoming int into string... which would invalidates my query.

Comment: The AWS server should not be converting `LIMIT 1` into anything other than exactly what it contains. If it is, their server is broken, and you should be reporting this serious bug to them so that it can be fixed.

Comment: *the aws server automatically converts incoming int into string...* Insert it into the query text as literal using concatenation, not as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LIMIT clause cannot take expressions or variables. Therefore if you absolutely need such functionality, you must do a huge workaround - you have to simulate it. Here is one variant:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM(
   SELECT product.*, @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rownum
   FROM product
   JOIN (SELECT @rownum:=0) AS t
) AS t1
JOIN (SELECT @limit:=CAST('1' AS UNSIGNED) AS thelimit) AS t2
JOIN (SELECT @offset:=2 AS theoffset) AS t3
WHERE t1.rownum>t3.theoffset AND t1.rownum <= t2.thelimit+t3.theoffset;
```

A detailed explanation is below:

1. The table t1 is generated by the following query:

   ```
   SELECT product.*, @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rownum
   FROM product
   JOIN (SELECT @rownum:=0) AS t
   ```

   In this query we practically select everything from the product table and attach a row number counter to every fetched row from it (using the @rownum variable which increments with 1 for every row).
2. The t2 table

   ```
   SELECT @limit:=CAST('1' AS UNSIGNED) AS thelimit
   ```

   is just your limit clause stored as variable.
3. The t3 table

   ```
   SELECT @offset:=5 AS theoffset
   ```

   is your offset
4. We then join those three tables and we apply condition

   ```
   WHERE t1.rownum>t3.theoffset AND t1.rownum <= t2.thelimit+t3.theoffset;
   ```

   by which we are simulating a regular LIMIT clause.

Furthermore - if you wish, you can use just @limit and @offset instead of t2.thelimit and t3.theoffset - it will work fine and it will be probably more readable for some people. The final query can simplify it's look a bit like this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM(
   SELECT product.*, @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rownum
   FROM product
   JOIN (SELECT @rownum:=0) AS t
) AS t1
JOIN (SELECT @limit:=CAST('1' AS UNSIGNED)) AS t2
JOIN (SELECT @offset:=2) AS t3
WHERE rownum>@offset AND rownum <= @limit+@offset;
```

or you can even skip the two JOINs if you declare the variables before executing the query (this may be a bit faster):

```
SET @limit:=CAST('1' AS UNSIGNED);
SET @offset:=2;
SELECT t1.*
FROM(
   SELECT product.*, @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rownum
   FROM product
   JOIN (SELECT @rownum:=0) AS t
) AS t1
WHERE rownum>@offset AND rownum <= @limit+@offset;
```